# Core Apps Not Launching After Installing OS X Mavericks

Tags: mac, macos

I Installed OS X Mavericks about a week ago, It worked fine at first but all of a sudden no core Apps will load.

Mail, iCal, App Store, Maps, iMessage all quit and log a console message "Exited with Code 1"

I have tried: rebooting, resetting the NVRAM, and booting my OS in safe mode. None fix the problem.

I really don't know how to fix this without doing a clean install and wonder if anyone has a solution to this more narrow than reinstalling the OS cleanly?

Comment: can I assume you have rebooted? the console could probably provide some useful feedback here.

Comment: I have rebooted, Reset the PRAM, Booted in safe mode... Can't think of anything else?

I can't install an update as the App store refuses to launch

:(

Comment: According to the Console the Apps have "Exited with Code 1"

Answer (score 2):

I managed to fix the issue by reinstalling OS X Mavericks

Here's how to fix it

1. Restart your machine
2. On boot hold Command and R
3. Choose to Reinstall OS X

System will restart as usual after install and OS X will be fully functional

You will NOT lose any settings or personal data with this method

:)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look hear to see if this solution helps you.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3826648

Comment: Can you provide more information than just a link that may become invalid?